# Is the minCompileSDK of jetpack compose 1.5 API level 34?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

Recently Jetpack Compose 1.5 was released, adding a dependency either using the compose POM

`implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))`

or directly using

`implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0")`

to a project using compileSDK = 33 results in two dependency issues

1. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.
2. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

Using API SDK 34, is currently not possible since there is no publicly available version of the android gradle plugin that supports it and secondly API 34 is still in beta.

Since I don't directly use the emoji2 dependency anywhere, this can be fixed using a build.gradle.kts similiar to the following.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force("androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.3.0")
                force("androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.3.0")
            }
        }
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.0")
}
```

Is this the best way to fix this issue, is this a dependency bug since all the dependencies are marked as stable but one of them has a dependency on a beta SDK. Incidentally, the emoji2 dependency is marked as requiring a minSdkVersion of 14, not 34.

The following issue was created on the google tracker by someone else as I was creating this question, I also encountered this issue with Kotlin plugin version 1.8.20.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295457468

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some newer Library versions, you have to use the latest CompileSDK Version. Add Below Code In `build.gradle(app-level)` in `defaultConfig`.

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
        ...
    }
```

}